# can i create a new class depending on some condition

Tags: java, class

can i create a class depending on whether a class with particular name exists or not such as
if i have a class name as A and another class as B
if both these classes exists only and only then a new class name as class C should get created (remember class A and class B are independent and not a nested class of any other class)

```
class A{}

class B{}

class main{

if(class A == true && class B == true)
{
//declaration of class C should get triggered
}
}
```

I have tried it with the forName() method. I think that would help you a bit to solve this.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Yes you can do that, check out the reflection API, available with `A.class` and `B.class` for example. But this really sounds like a bad approach. Reflection is almost always a bad approach to anything, except you really really need it. For example for *meta programming*, such as developing developer tools like debuggers. Please explain what you actually want to achieve instead of asking about your idea of how to tackle it. This is called **XY problem**.

Comment: Link which explains what we mean by [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).